# Custom brightness is ignored in full-screen applications

Tags: 20.04, display, screen, brightness, vlc

I'm using the brightness slider on Ubuntu 20.04 to manually adjust the screen brightness.

However, this custom setting is disregarded as soon as I activate full-screen mode for any application (e.g. watching a video via VLC player or running a game via Steam). Instead, the brightness is increased to the maximum brightness, while the full-screen window is active.

Is there a way to also run full-screen applications with reduced/custom brightness?